# Run a Python program on a WAMP server

Tags: python

I am trying to run Python program on WAMP. Can you tell me how to deal with it? I have downloaded the file `mod_wsgi.so` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi 
and placed it in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\modules`.

I have configured my `httpd.conf` file as follows:

- `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` and saved the file.
- Refreshed WAMP.
- When I tried to run the `helloworld.py` file I it is simply displaying the code in browser.

My Python file contains only the statement:

```
print "Hello World"
```

please help me out to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to run a Python file which doesn't return anything related to your web application, then WSGI is not the ideal thing for you.

WSGI is a Web Application platform where you can code your Web Application using python while conforming to WSGI interface. Then your entire application should be something like this.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

For more information read this [post](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide)

Comment: my python program actually connects to database and does some operations with this database. i am able to connect to database on my local computer but i can't connect to database on a web hosting site. my python program is going to run from my local computer itself but the database need to be connected from web hosting site. is there any way for this